# swift get values from array and put them into another array using recursion function

Tags: arrays, function, swift, recursion

I want to get values from one array, and put them into another array using recursion function.And want to notice that I do not want to use loop(like 'for in loop')

```
var rudics = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
var array = [""]
func changeArray (var new:[String]) {
    array = [new.first!]
    if new.count > 0 {
    new.removeLast()
    changeArray(new)
    }
}

changeArray(rudics)
```

it gives me an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Playground execution failed: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

and so on..

please help me!

Comment: the error might be at `array = [new.first!]`. You are doing it before checking for `new.count` and `new` might be empty at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider something like this:

```
var rudics = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
var array = [String]()
func changeArray (var new:[String]) {
    if let first = new.first {
        array.append(first)
        new.removeAtIndex(0)
        changeArray(new)
    }
}

changeArray(rudics)
```

Comment: when I call 'array' it gives [one", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one"]

Comment: Yep ... edited it. It was due to the fact that in your first example you take the first item but remove the last

Comment: You might consider correcting it in your question, since it was not central to the problem you posted.

Comment: Just it confused because I tried to reverse this array last time :) .At first I wrote new.removeAtIndex(0) as you did . :)

Comment: If I want to use optional value like new.first, should I always use optional binding? not just if statement?thats why my code shows an error?

Comment: Your code shows an error since it _force unwrap_ an optional value using `!`. When you force unwrap an optional you are saying _I am sure this contains a value and is not `Nothing`_. Then when your program reaches the empty array, `first` is `Nothing` and you force unwrap it pretending it is a value ... and **crash**. So yes, generally speaking you should always check  that an optional value contains an actual value _before_ using it's supposed actual value.

Comment: thanks for a comment. but when I write new.first! , there is a value.. I know that variable 'array' is an empty at first time, but in new.first! should be a value, because in array 'new' assigned an array of 'rudics'. thats why I can not understand of showing an error..

Comment: In your code you check that `new` is not empty _after_ the force unwrap of `new.first!`. Thus when your recursion reaches the empty _new_ (i.e.: `[]`), your program crashes right the line before `if new.count > 0 { ...`. By the way, you can check if an array is empty whit the shorter `new.isEmpty`